# vpnc timeout on Oracle DB

Tags: vpn, oracle, sqlplus

We are using a VPN to connect with our Oracle Database. We use vpnc and start it with: `vpnc /etc/vpnc/our.conf`
After that we execute our firewall script. We use `sqlplus64` to verify the connection and this is working fine. We launch some apps to get some data from the database. It all works well. But now we're a couple of houres later and the connection seems to be gone. 
The "solution" for us was to find the pid of our vpnc and kill it. After that we restart vpnc and it all works fine again for a couple of houres.

The Oracle code we got when it fails is a timeout: `ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`

We also checked our tunnel (which is tun1) for us and it still exist. We also took a look to the logs which were only displaying some things when we were manually killing and restarting vpnc.

Someone who has any experience with this issue?

Comment: Can you get any other communication through the tunnel (like ping) when this happens or is the tunnel dead? This sounds like different SA lifetimes to me.

Comment: I have to use tnsping for this?

Comment: Is there a way to check the SA lifetime?